# call java methods with argumenrs in JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, jnienv

I am working on JNI program and I am not able to call a java method from my C++ program.

The code snippet of java method is here

```
public static void getTables(Connection conn) throws Exception {

    String TABLE_NAME = "TABLE_NAME";
    String TABLE_SCHEMA = "TABLE_SCHEM";
    String[] TABLE_TYPES = {"TABLE"};
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();

    ResultSet tables = dbmd.getTables(null, null, null, TABLE_TYPES);
    while (tables.next()) {
      System.out.println(tables.getString(TABLE_NAME));
          System.out.println(tables.getString(TABLE_SCHEMA));
    }
  }
```

And I want to call this java method from C++ program.

I am able to call the main method 
for that the code is

```
midMain       = env->GetStaticMethodID(clsH, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

I want to call getTables method like this. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Are you having trouble with getting the method id, creating the Connection parameter or calling the method? Show that code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872927/755804
and probably these:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021142/755804
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941319/755804
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21109940/755804

There is some difference between calling static and non-static methods, but not much.
I suggest you start with something that works and gradually change it to what you want.