# Want to create library project that contain all my (native) android application view adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to manage my (native) android application code.For that reason i have been working and create modular approach in which i have already done with my library projects of db , json parser and data models.
But when i am trying to do it with view adapters there is the involvment of R file for getting views id.
So, is there any other way so that i can manage my android listview adapter.
or there is the way to pass the R file complete.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call Java from C++. Please see the links at
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24584731/755804

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass R from app project to library it is meaningless.

You can pass to adapter id itself. adapter.setViewIds(R.layout.item, R.id.textView, R.id.title)

Or, you can create ids in library projects.

Comment: Thanks for your anticipation.
So,after your reply i think view adapter should not be in library project.

Comment: Take a look at ArrayAdapter source code, you could use something like that.